# SQL Loader Oracle: How to load predefined values

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am uploading the data with SQL Loader, in the file.txt file I have 3 fields and I want to load the field UPLOAD_DATE with sysdate and FILE_NAME with 'archivo.txt'

I tried to do something like this with SQL Loader, for example:

```
UPLOAD_DATE DATE TERMINATED BY "|" sysdate,
FILE_NAME CHAR(200) TERMINATED BY "|" "archivo.txt"
```

but this does not work, there is another way to load this information

Error

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 14.
Expecting "," or ")", found keyword sysdate.
UPLOAD_DATE DATE TERMINATED BY "|" SYSDATE,
```

ControlFile.ctl

```
OPTIONS (SILENT=(ALL, HEADER))
load data
infile file.txt
badfile file.bad
discardfile file.dis
append
into table TABLE_INFO
fields terminated by '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS (
  SUB_ID INTEGER EXTERNAL TERMINATED BY "|",
  SUB_PROPERTY CHAR(4000) TERMINATED BY "|",
  MODIFY_TIME DATE TERMINATED BY "|" "to_date(:MODIFY_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')",
  UPLOAD_DATE DATE TERMINATED BY "|" "to_date(:UPLOAD_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')",
  FILE_NAME CHAR(200) TERMINATED BY "|"
)
```

Table

```
create table TABLE_INFO
(
  sub_id       NUMBER(20) not null,
  sub_property VARCHAR2(4000),
  modify_time  DATE,
  upload_date  DATE,
  file_name    VARCHAR2(200)
)
```

file.txt

```
11|campo2|09/13/2017 11:36:11 PM
12|campo1|09/22/2017 02:41:38 PM
```

```
sqlldr userbd/passbd control=ControlFile.ctl log=log_file.log rows=10000 direct=true
```

Comment: What does, "this does not work" mean? Please post errors

Comment: @OldProgrammer
Errors
```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 14.

Expecting "," or ")", found keyword sysdate.

UPLOAD_DATE DATE TERMINATED BY "|" SYSDATE,
```

Comment: What are you expecting the `terminated by` clause to do when you're supplying a value from the control file - when there is no field in the data file to be terminated? And is there a reason you're specifying it again for each field anyway, when you've set it as the default `fields` setting?

Comment: @AlexPoole How should I configure the control file?

Answer (score 2):

You have already used the trailing null cols, you can now use the constant value as follows:

```
UPLOAD_DATE DATE sysdate,
FILE_NAME constant "archivo.txt"
```